# Why GLPI LDAP Authentification fails with test error?

Tags: ldap, samba

i'm running a samba domain controller and i'd like to import my users from my AD server to glpi but the test keeps failling i don't know what could be the problem.
I edited my hosts file with the server'IP address and its FQDN and also checked the kinit administrator which worked all right so there's no problem apperently with the ldap.
There's nothing as well in the logs
I'll be glad if anyone could give me an idea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EfXF.png)